# Appropriate distribution for continuous, positive and bimodal response variable in glmm

Tags: mixed-model, glmm

I am seeking assistance on choosing appropriate distribution for glmms. My response variable is continuous, positive & bimodal with minimum value 0.35 and maximum value 100. Is Gamma (link = "log") right choice here? I have attached histogram & density plot here. Thank you for any assistance! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are showing us the *marginal* distribution, while models like GLM’s or GLMMs are defined in terms of *conditional* distributions and make no assumptions about marginals.
- Your dependent variable is bounded, so using Gamma distribution would not prevent the model from predicting the severities over 100%. You need bounded distribution here. Can the severity be understood as probability of something? If yes, you can use binomial link. If not, one choice could be beta regression.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In this study, plants were inoculated and disease severity was assessed 3-6 times a year. Disease severity was determined by estimating  percentage of leaf area with disease (0 to 100%), so my response variable is showing percentages. I can divide the values by 100 and make the response variable 0-1 bound, but severity will not be representing probability rather it would be representing proportion of disease. So I should go with beta regression then? Do I need to try a specific link with beta distribution? Or simply family = beta_family() in glmmtmb will do?

Comment: I also assume I can not have the response variable as percentages now. That is, I will need to divide values in response variable by 100 to make it 0-1 bound in order to use beta regression? Thanks again

Comment: @AhsaanKhan beta regression is not a GLM so there is no link for it. I didn’t use glmtmb, so cannot comment. As about final question, yes, you’d need to divide by 100.

Comment: sorry I meant can I use glmm with beta family? I am not familiar with beta regression, so want to make things easier for myself if possible. Thanks very much for your time

Comment: @AhsaanKhan technically it's not GLM but it's almost the same.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I have up voted your answer. I'd try beta family in glmm first and then binomial if results were misleading. By the way, I'd use "logit" link if I had to choose binomial distribution. Is that right? Cheers

Comment: @AhsaanKhan correct.